# Freeze on Top in Excell office web app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

I tried to create Freeze on Top using excel and it working fine using Excel 2016 however not available using office web app. I am using SharePOint 2013 on premise. Is this feature available?. I read the following 2016 post and it said still not available. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f9717c8-7c44-4576-9d3f-48acd3107c96/office-web-app-freeze-row-not-working?forum=sharepointadmin

Anyone know more information about when Freeze on Top will release or has been released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There too limited features available in office web app. Unfortunately freez option is not available on Office Webapp.

Alco there is no official information about Freeze freature will release.

You may also consider referring the link below:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6?CorrelationId=52af30b4-c405-4886-9dd6-8880c23b46b2&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010369179